# scrollTop returns 0 for all document elements in javascript but scroll event fires on body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, scroll

I made an event handler for the scroll event on the body tag which fires correctly. However when I try to find the position of the scollbar using scrollTop(), I was unable to do so. To figure out which element was being scrolled I logged the scrollTop() of all the DOM elements but surprisingly all were 0.

```
$('body').scroll(function () {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
        console.log('scrolltop', all[i].scrollTop);
    }
});
```

All I want to know is the position of the scrollbar and whether the scrollbar has reached the end or not. I have tried $(document).scroll() and $(window).scroll, but none of them fires. The event only works on the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `window` object is usually the most reliable for tracking scrolling.

ScrollTop also only really tracks how much the window has been scrolled and although commonly confused for doing so, it **does not** track how far an element is from the top of the page. For that you need to use `offset`.

As such I have simply changed your code to run on the `window` scroll and also changed your logic to use jQuerys `each` function which will make things simpler.:

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('*').each(function (){
        console.log(
        'Element Text:', $(this).text(),
          ' | From Top', $(this).offset().top
      );
    })
});
```

With the above JS you will see in your console the following output:

`Element Text: hello87  | From Top 1556`

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wigster/t1e3dee8/1/